# Ajax Datatables with two data arrays

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable where it's filled using ajax call to backend, the problem is that not all rows data is returned in one array, but two

Where the first row has first column from data1[0] and second column from data2[0].
is that achievable with ajax calls ?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var DataTable=$('#my-table').DataTable( {

            "lengthMenu": [[10,25,50,100, -1], [10,25,50,100, "All"]],
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "responsive": true,
            "ajax":{
        url:'backendAPILink',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                complete:function (response) {
            }}
        } );
    } )
```

Example of returned json

```
{


  "data1": {
    "a": "b",
    "c": "d",
    "e": "f"
  },
  "data2": {
    "h": "o",
    "i": "p",
    "j": "q"
  }
}
```

so the first row is b o
second d p

Comment: Please show an example of the returned JSON.

Comment: @davidkonrad added

Comment: That was really schematic :) Is there a continous string of `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4` etc that not is an array, or is `data1` and `data2` holding arrays of items? I have the feeling the listed JSON is showing a concept.

Comment: yes its just the concept but it's two arrays, but the difference is that the the array element may contain another array, but that example will do

Comment: But you do not have arrays in the JSON example ...